# Getting Updated Value from Input with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql

I am writing a page with Jquery / Javascript that dynamically adds rows to a table.  The table contains input fields for date and time.  There is a button to add a new line and I've been able to write code so that a new line that picks up the previous date and time.

The problem is, if the user changes the value in one of the inputs, an added row doesn't pick up the new, displayed value but the value that was there when the row was first added.  E.g. if the row was created with 2015-01-19 and the user changed it to 2015-01-20 then new row doesn't pick up that displayed value but the original value.

I've hunted everywhere and have tried a .on( "change") command but it's not working.  Any ideas?

Comment: By "The previous" do you mean "The value from the input in the row above" or "The value the user last entered on any row"?

Comment: Also, your current code and perhaps a jsFiddle example would be nice.

Comment: Sorry - of course: http://jsfiddle.net/Tony_wh/482j3vev/ The rows are added without problem but try changing one of the inputs and then adding a row; it uses the original value not the value of the box when the add link is clicked. Thanks for the rapid reply.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution: http://web-profile.com.ua/jquery/dev/jquery-input-value-change-keyup/ I will try to get to it tomorrow - it's bedtime here in the UK!